# How did "womanizer" develop its current meaning?

Tags: etymology, semantic-shift

A ***[womanizer](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/womanizer)*** is:

> - a man who always seems to have a new girlfriend, and who has no hesitation about starting up a new relationship before he's ended the last one. Usually, these relationships are sexual and don't last long. The noun womanizer comes from the verb womanize. (Vocabulary.com)

***to [womanize:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/womanize?ref=etymonline_crossreference)***

> - 1590s, "to make effeminate," from woman + -ize. ***Sense of "to chase women, to go wenching" is attested from 1893.*** (Etymonline)

I couldn't find the reason  why the term changed its meaning but I guessed it was probably influenced by the increase in popularity in England in the late 19th c. of a character like Casanova, a most famous womanizer:

> "man of carnal adventures, connoisseur of seduction," ***1888, from [Giacomo Girolamo Casanova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giacomo_Casanova) de Seignalt*** (1725-1798), the infamous debaucher.

Question:

Can anybody provide more information about the change in usage of the term womanize?

Comment: Pure speculation: the original usage was uncommon enough that whoever used it to mean "to chase women" in 1893 probably thought they were making it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first instance of *womanize*, ‘to emaculate, make feminine/effeminate’ dates from the time men wore velvet, lace collars, and a large pearl earring if their wealth permitted:

> for as the loue of heauen makes one heauenly, the loue of vertue, vertuous; so doth the loue of the world make one become worldly, and this effeminate loue of a woman, doth so womanize a man, that (if hee yeeld to it) it will not onely make him an amazon; but a launder, a distaff-spinner; or what so euer other vile occupation their idle heads can imagin and their weake hands performe: — Sir Philip Sidney, *The Countesse of Pembrokes Arcadia*, 1593. EEBO

*Womanizer* in the Casanova sense dates at least to 1822, where the word appears in a still hilarious article about the recent erection of a statue commemorating the Duke of Wellington.  British women had subscribed to fund the statue, raising some £10,000, roughly [£1.17 million](http://www.in2013dollars.com/1822-GBP-in-2016?amount=10000) in pre-Brexit currency, and decided that the perfect way to honor the hero of Waterloo was with a classical nude (but for a figleaf) of Achilles:

> It is true, that as the Duke is a great [*womanizer*](https://books.google.de/books?id=KKBkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA340&dq=%22womanizer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwislKTozcbfAhVMsKQKHc2mBag4FBDoAQg7MAU), they might, if they had pleased, have placed, with equal propriety, a beautiful naked Venus on this pedestal; but that would not have been so agreeable to themselves. “Mr. Achilles; or The Ladies’ Man,” *The Rambler’s Magazine*, 1/8 (1 Aug. 1822), 340.

Though married, the duke and his wife lived mostly apart; his various [affairs and liasons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Wellesley,_1st_Duke_of_Wellington#Family) were common knowledge.

[image]

Wellington Monument, London, [*Source*](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/hawksites.newpaltz.edu/dist/3/85/files/2015/11/2e-1adzvfd.jpg)

The older meaning of *womanize*, ‘emasculate’ was not supplanted by ‘chase women for casual affairs’; the new meaning was simply added on. The word *train*, for instance, existed before the railroad.

> “Gary Hart [*womanized*](https://books.google.de/books?id=a-tNAQAAIAAJ&q=%22womanized%22&dq=%22womanized%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju3PHC3MbfAhWhlosKHaQzBbs4FBDoAQgzMAM): Al Gore risks being *womanized*.” Whether neoliberals are sexually aggressive or skittish, they all seem to fear womanization. — *Vanity Fair* 51, 42, 1988.

*Womanized* in the sexual sense is intransitive.  A *womanizer* simply *womanizes* — Gary Hart womanized. When reinforcing the speaker’s notion of masculinity, *womanize* is often used in the passive voice, but a man
*is womanized* by some person, action or circumstance. According to this writer, Al Gore risks *being womanized* by some unstated agent. In the *Arcadia*, worldly love for a woman womanizes a man.

> Although he is a womaniser, this activity paradoxically womanises him, for it immerses him in a sensuous existence stereotypically associated with the feminine and running counter to the life of self-denial espoused by Lisa's husband.  — Gale Research Company,  *Twentieth-century Literary Criticism*, 1999, 232.